# How to add space between two divs in HTML?

Tags: html

I have two divs declared as,

```
<div id="icdAid" align="center" ></div>
<div id="errorMsg" align="center" ></div>
```

How can I add space between them?

Comment: you should use css for that

Comment: `align="center"` has been deprecated for some time. Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your CSS

```
#icdAid
{
   margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

This will add a space of 10px to the bottom of `icdAid` div.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/baXmu/130/)**

Comment: Div's are not floated!

Comment: @Justinas:- Hmm.. Missed that.

Answer (score 0):

In html - use `<br/>` to add new line.
In css - `#icAid{ margin-bottom: 20px; }`.
Also `align` attribute is deprecated, use css for that `div{ text-align: center; }`

Comment: correct version is <br> not <br/> since html5, and you should never use <br> for element spacing, it can only be used for new line in text, any other usage is just wrong.

Comment: @pankijs not necessarily. depending on your doctype, you can use either HTML5 or XHTML5. both are valid modern options, and XHTML5 uses the self-closing tags.

Comment: is OP asking for xhtml or html solution? anyway using <br> anywhere other than inside <p> tag to start text in new line is just wrong.

Comment: @pankijs i know no other way to do it in pure `html`, just `<br/>` to add space. Yes, it's wrong, but question tagged as `html`.

Answer (score 0):

Your should use the CSS solution

`#icdAid {
margin-bottom: 15px;
}`

This is used if you want the results replicated to wherever you use the `icdAid` id. But if you want a fix on a single page use `<br/>` tags in-between the close and open tags of you `<div>`'s.

With the CSS solution you have more control over the spacing as `<br/>` tags are a set width.